# Define a trait to be extended by case class in scala

Tags: scala, traits, case-class, self-type

I have some case classes which have a method `tupled` defined in its companion object. As it can be seen from the code below in companion objects, it is just code duplication.

```
case class Book(id: Int, isbn: String, name: String)

object Book {
  def tupled = (Book.apply _).tupled // Duplication
}


case class Author(id: Int, name: String)

object Author {
  def tupled = (Author.apply _).tupled // Duplication
}
```

From another question ([can a scala self type enforce a case class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674602/can-a-scala-self-type-enforce-a-case-class-type)), it seems like we can not enforce the self-type of a trait to be a case class.

Is there a way to define a trait (say `Tupled`) that can be applied as following?

```
// What would be value of ???
trait Tupled {
  self: ??? =>

  def tupled = (self.apply _).tupled
}

// Such that I can replace tupled definition with Trait
object Book extends Tupled {
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because there's no relationship between `FunctionN` types in Scala, it's not possible to do this without arity-level boilerplate somewhere—there's just no way to abstract over the companion objects' `apply` methods without enumerating all the possible numbers of members.

You could do this by hand with a bunch of `CompanionN[A, B, C, ...]` traits, but that's pretty annoying. [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides a much better solution, which allows you to write something like the following:

```
import shapeless.{ Generic, HList }, shapeless.ops.product.ToHList

class CaseClassCompanion[C] {
  def tupled[P <: Product, R <: HList](p: P)(implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
    toR: ToHList.Aux[P, R]
  ): C = gen.from(toR(p))
}
```

And then:

```
case class Book(id: Int, isbn: String, name: String)
object Book extends CaseClassCompanion[Book]

case class Author(id: Int, name: String)
object Author extends CaseClassCompanion[Author]
```

Which you can use like this:

```
scala> Book.tupled((0, "some ISBN", "some name"))
res0: Book = Book(0,some ISBN,some name)

scala> Author.tupled((0, "some name"))
res1: Author = Author(0,some name)
```

You might not even want the `CaseClassCompanion` part, since it's possible to construct a generic method that converts tuples to case classes (assuming the member types line up):

```
class PartiallyAppliedProductToCc[C] {
  def apply[P <: Product, R <: HList](p: P)(implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
    toR: ToHList.Aux[P, R]
  ): C = gen.from(toR(p))
}

def productToCc[C]: PartiallyAppliedProductToCc[C] =
  new PartiallyAppliedProductToCc[C]
```

And then:

```
scala> productToCc[Book]((0, "some ISBN", "some name"))
res2: Book = Book(0,some ISBN,some name)

scala> productToCc[Author]((0, "some name"))
res3: Author = Author(0,some name)
```

This will work for case classes with up to 22 members (since the `apply` method on the companion object can't be eta-expanded to a function if there are more than 22 arguments).

Comment: As a side note, `fromTuple` might be a better name for this method—it's true that you're tupling the `apply`, but calling the result `tupled` makes is sound like the conversion is _to_ a tuple instead of _from_.

Comment: @TravisBrown How can I achieve the same effect with case classes of 1 parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the signature of `apply` differs from case to case, and that there is no common trait for these functions. `Book.tupled` and `Author.tupled` basically have the same code, but have very different signatures. Therefore, the solution may not be as nice as we'd like.

---

I can conceive of a way using an annotation macro to cut out the boilerplate. Since there isn't a nice way to do it with the standard library, I'll resort to code generation (which still has compile-time safety). The caveat here is that annotation macros require the use of the [macro paradise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) compiler plugin. Macros must also be in a separate compilation unit (like another sbt sub-project). Code that uses the annotation would also require the use of the macro paradise plugin.

```
import scala.annotation.{ StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly }
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class Tupled extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro tupledMacroImpl.impl
}

object tupledMacroImpl {

  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val result = annottees map (_.tree) match {
      // A case class with companion object, we insert the `tupled` method into the object
      // and leave the case class alone.
      case (classDef @ q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }")
        :: (objDef @ q"object $objName extends { ..$objEarlyDefs } with ..$objParents { $objSelf => ..$objDefs }")
        :: Nil if mods.hasFlag(Flag.CASE) =>
        q"""
          $classDef
          object $objName extends { ..$objEarlyDefs } with ..$objParents { $objSelf => 
            ..$objDefs
            def tupled = ($objName.apply _).tupled
          }
        """
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annotation target: must be a companion object of a case class.")
    }

    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
@Tupled
case class Author(id: Int, name: String)

object Author


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Author
defined object Author

scala> Author.tupled
res0: ((Int, String)) => Author = <function1>
```

---

Alternatively, something like this may be possible with shapeless. See @TravisBrown's better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.