# How to utilize Scala case class copy() functionality in a generic class

Tags: scala, generics, copy, case-class

My domain classes are case classes and I have general engine/transformer classes that operate on them.  I make use of case class functionality such as `copy()` and would like to do that while treating the classes generically, here is a simple example:

```
trait Fruit { val color: String }

case class Apple (color: String = "red") extends Fruit

case class Banana (color: String = "yellow") extends Fruit

case class Orange (color: String = "orange") extends Fruit

val apple = new Apple
val newApple1 = apple.copy(color = "green") // compiles fine

object Transformer {
  def apply(fruit: Fruit): Fruit = {
    fruit.copy(color = "green") // does not compile, "Cannot resolve symbol copy"
  }
}

val newApple2 = Transformer(apple)

newApple2
```

In this example the first call to `copy()` works fine, but trying to do the same kind of operation within the `apply()` method of the `Transformer` class does not, I am assuming because Scala does not know that `Fruit` is a case class and thus has the runtime-generated `copy()` method.

I've tried various typecasts, for example making `Fruit` an abstract class or having it extend `scala.Product` (which internally is the closest ancestor to the case class) but this doesn't make the `copy()` method available.

I would rather not implement the copy method myself if I can avoid it, though with reflection or shapeless it can probably be done in a generic way that would work.

There are a few other similar questions here on StackOverflow but I have not see an answer that addresses this, thanks for any info.

EDIT: My question is similar to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995639/scala-how-to-define-an-abstract-copyable-superclass-for-any-case-class) however the answers there did not satisfy me for these reasons:

- The accepted solution suggested implementing a `copyWithId()` method, or, in other words, a special-purpose `copy()` method that takes one or more specific parameters, whereas I want to use the very versatile case class `copy()` method which accepts variable parameters.
- The solutions proposed there use shapeless or lenses and a lot of Scala "magic" which it seems to me should not be necessary since, as my example shows, the `copy()` implementation that I'm after is already in scope, but is just not available because the correct data type can't be inferred. I'm hoping instead to gain access to the `copy()` with the right kind of typecast.

Comment: I saw that answer and don't believe it addresses my question, I edited my question to explain why.

Comment: The problem here is that all your example `Fruit` instances _happen_ to have a `copy()` method but they don't _have_ to have it. You could create a `class Grape( ...` that extends `Fruit` and, because it's not a case class, it won't have a `copy()` method unless you give it one. One solution is to use pattern matching to identify exactly what type has been passed to `apply()` and then call its `copy()` method if it has one, but that's not the clean/concise code you're looking for.

Comment: My domain classes all have a copy() method because they are case classes, and if there were a way to define Fruit as a trait or abstract class that indicated this, with a type or ancestor, or to include the signature for the copy() method somehow, then it seems that methods that took Fruit as a parameter would know that copy is available.  I don't think that this question has been adequately answered on SO if you could un-mark it as a duplicate I'd like to get input from the community, thanks.

Comment: You need 5 votes to reopen. Right now you have 4 (mine is one of them), but asking a new, clearer, question might be the better way to go. I suspect what you want might not be possible. As [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674602/can-a-scala-self-type-enforce-a-case-class-type) demonstrates, it _is_ possible to require all Fruits be case classes but that still doesn't make `copy()` a member method of `Fruit`.

Comment: Perhaps this is doable with a macro to implicitly create a typeclass? i.e. `trait Foo[A] { def copyAndChangeColor(a: A, color: String): A }` and `implicit def makeFoo[A <: Fruit]: Foo[A] = macro makeFooImpl[A]` where makeFooImpl would construct an expression instantiating a `Foo` that calls the `copy` method appropriately... but all this seems way more complicated than just defining an abstract `copyWithColor(color: String)` method on the `Fruit` trait and implementing it in all the subclasses. It's not clever or short, but it's very simple.